# Asp.net required field validator issue with jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, asp.net, accordion

I am facing problems in .Net 4.5 that asp.net required field validator is not working in jquery dialog box.

Getting error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method
>   'dcAccordion'"

To place JQuery accordian menu:

```
[Code snip]
$('#accordion').dcAccordion({
                eventType: 'click',
                autoClose: true,
                saveState: true,
                disableLink: true,
                speed: 'slow',
                showCount: true,
                autoExpand: true,
                cookie: 'dcjq-accordion',
                classExpand: 'dcjq-current-parent'
            });
```

To use JQuery dialog:
[code snip]

```
$("#" + dialogID).dialog({
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
    });
```

and if place asp.net require field validators on jquery dialog then dialog does not open and get above error...

but if I remove the validators then it works fine...

need help

thanks

Comment: Your Question is not  all clear, remember always give us some code to see any problem. The only that I can say is check the jQuery library, I think you are missing one.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your instant reply, I am using Jquery accordian in my website and jquery dialog. its work fine. but if I use asp.net required field validators for the controls placed in JQuery dialog then jquery fails to open dialog and give error of accordian "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dcAccordion'"

Comment: Please let me know if the issue is still not clear then I will place code snippets

Comment: I have updated the content in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to script reference position. To resolve my issue I had to add accordian script reference as the last script reference on the page like no other script reference should be added after accoridan script reference. So I placed the file reference at end of the HTML file. It works in my case. Thanks!